# Addiction to fitness help

Tags: weightlifting, motivation

So I finally got a job that starts in February. During my studies and job finding days I always have made fitness my top priority in life. I always plan my workouts in the morning, and which days, and what food I eat. This admittedly has caused me a lot of stress, such as sometimes unable to sleep because I keep thinking on how much sleep I can get that night and how much gains will I lose if I don't sleep that night (I'm actually writing this at 5 am in the morning because I can't sleep due to precisely this reason), or that I can't enjoy eating outside with friends due to me thinking of how much calories I eat during that period.

Even during the pandemic I always try to get my workouts in, even if it is raining outside and I have to do pull--ups wearing a raincoat, or even if it is below 0 degrees Celcius outside and the calisthenics bars near my home are freezing. I think fitness is so addicting to me because I think of fitness as a way to keep my weight stable (I can eat my current favourite diet without gaining any weight), but more importantly because I keep gaining strength. Two years ago I couldn't do a single pull-up; now I could do 20 easily. When lockdown started last march I could not do a single pistol squat and one-hand push ups. Now I could do 10 of each easily. It's these long, arduous but eventually frutiful winnings that makes it so addicting; I feel like I am a failure in many aspects of life (social life, studies, etc.) that these winnings become sort of a "payback" to the parts of me that fail me. I also had an issue with being overweight and went into a very strict diet that got me super skinny, and I am afraid that if I stop working out and got stressed with work then I will binge eat to remove my stress and regain the weight I lost and I will be back to my miserable state (as if I'm not miserable now...).

But now I am about to start a career, and I am super grateful to get a job in this disaster we are all in. But I'm afraid that my fitness addiction will take over and I will lose sleep or be unnecessarily stressed and can't do my job well. How can I at least reduce this addiction? I don't want to sabotage my career just so I can do handstand push-ups one day, but I just can't be consistent with this vow.

Comment: How much time do you need for these workouts? How frequently? You don't need to workout 24/7 to stay fit; life is all about balance.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this makes me nostalgic lol. I can totally relate to what you're going through. I was in that addicted phase as well, but never really seen it until after I got out. Worrying about sleep, tracking calories, taking the bus in the snow to go hit a deadlift or squat pr, skipping fireworks with the girl of my dreams on Canada Day to workout, I feel you man. Luciano is right though, life really is all about balance, if I was still in that addicted phase, I wouldn't be where I am today, not that I'm a multimillionaire or anything, but I am for sure in a better place mentally, financially, and socially. I've lost all my gains, but I realized I want to be financially free more than just being jacked in life, it's easier to get jacked than to get rich. The best part about being rich is you actually have the time to get jacked, if you're jacked but poor, life isn't really the greatest and I could say that cause I've experienced it. You might start this career and lose some gains, but this career might open your eyes to something new and create new goals in your life, or you could still be addicted to the gym and stressed. The choice is yours, that's the beauty of life :).

Comment: This is more of a discussion response than anything. I encourage you to read through the help sections on questions and answers, it seems like a few of your answers are discussion forum types. We expect answers to be focused, and supported if possible. Welcome to the site!